# iOS-11 Paste menu disappears quickly

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios11, copy-paste

I have a strange error that I don't know how to even start debugging.

The "Paste" menu that comes up when a user wants to paste something into a text field stays up only for a fraction of a second and then disappears automatically again. This happens for all `UITextField`s in the app, both on the iPhone itself, and in the simulator. But it only happens on iOS 11, I have tried on a iOS 10.3.1 simulator, and there it works fine (the menu stays up).

There is nothing special about the fields in my app, as far as I know. But I have tried it with a brand new project as well, with an app with only one text field in it, and there it works fine. So it must be something in my app that causes it.

Any ideas are welcome.

---

For debugging purposes, I have implemented a notification handler for `UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification` in order to see what is causing it. Here is the stack trace when that happens:

```
#6  0x00000001147598f2 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#7  0x0000000112c5b6d6 in -[UIMenuController(UICalloutBarDelegateConformance) calloutBar:willStartAnimation:] ()
#8  0x0000000112c39c37 in -[UICalloutBar _fadeAfterCommand:] ()
#9  0x0000000112c12390 in -[UITextSelectionView removeFromSuperview] ()
#10 0x0000000112c13d30 in -[UITextSelectionView updateSelectionRectsIfNeeded] ()
#11 0x0000000112c13c90 in __51-[UITextSelectionView deferredUpdateSelectionRects]_block_invoke ()
#12 0x0000000115d93c07 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x0000000115d93b5e in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#14 0x0000000115d77fe3 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x0000000115d77889 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x0000000119dc19c6 in GSEventRunModal ()
#17 0x00000001125b25d6 in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x000000010dec3eb4 in main at /Users/rene/Projects/Flyskyhy/Flyskyhy/main.m:17
#19 0x00000001121e7d81 in start ()
```

---

EDIT: If I tap the text field multiple times in a row, then the Paste menu comes up and disappears every time. I have now discovered that the time between the disappearances is always an exact number of seconds. So it is likely that some timer is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If the app writes to any UITextField while the Paste menu is up, the menu will disappear. This is even the case if it is writing to another UITextField that is in a totally different UIView, and even not visible on screen. In my case, I had a clock field somewhere that was updated every second.

I have reported the bug to Apple. It is present at least in iOS version V11.2. Pre-iOS-11 versions, like V10.3.1, do not show the bug.

As work-around, I now use the following UITextField subclass instead of UITextField itself. It prevents changes to the field while the menu is up. It seems to do the job:

```
@implementation UITextFieldWrapper {
    bool pasteMenuActive;
    NSString *latestText;
}

- (void) setText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (!pasteMenuActive) {
        [super setText:text];
    } else {
        latestText = text;
    }
}

- (void) updatePasteMenu:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    pasteMenuActive = (notification.name == UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification);
    if (!pasteMenuActive && latestText != nil) {
        self.text = latestText;
        latestText = nil;
    }
}

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        return nil;
    }
    pasteMenuActive = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updatePasteMenu:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updatePasteMenu:) name:UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem but with custom cell (both collectionviewcell and tableviewcell). I ve solved the problem adding in viewDidLoad these:

```
UIMenuController.shared.update()
UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = true
```